# How to get a fortran90 code migrated to eclipse(photran) on windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse, fortran, migrate

I have been given a new project. I need to get a fortran code from a linux system working on windows. I'd like to be able to use Eclipse (photran) as my editor. What do I need to do to move things over? I've tried just dumping the source into a new eclipse project and it didn't work. Make had issues. What changes will I need to apply to the makefile or directory structure to get eclipse to run the program as it was?

The code at present has the main directory having a small make file that calls a larger make file located in the src directory down one level.

Using windows XP64, Eclipse3.6Helios, photran6.0, gfortran compiler, MinGW installed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gfortran on both sides and gnu make on both sides, I'm not real sure what would be different to cause you issues. Most likely targets would be things like external system calls, etc.

I would suggest you *get it to work under Eclipse on Linux first*, then port the working Eclipse-ready system to your MinGW environment. That should help separate the Eclipse environment issues from the Linux vs. MinGW environment issues.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. I have a working eclipse linux that i can move this to and test out.